# Not defined object in javascript built with Gulp

Tags: javascript, amd

I'm making a javascript application and I'm using Gulp to concatenate the .js files.

I have my app.js

```
var event = EventController.getAll();
```

and a controller i called events.js

```
EventController = {
    getAll: function(){
        return "event";
    }
}
```

I build the app directory with gulp into a single dist.js that looks like

```
var event = EventController.getAll();

EventController = {
    getAll: function(){
        return "event";
    }
}
```

Now i get an error when I call my controller because it hasn't been declared yet when I call it on the first row.

I know I could change the concatenation order to put the controller declaration before it is used, but I would like to know if there is a kind of a trick that could make me ignore the concatenation order like wrapping everything on an onload callback or something like.

Can anybody suggest me something ?

Comment: You should use Browserify or another module system.

Comment: Use es6 modules + webpack